How to Align Zero Points of Dual Y-Axes in Recharts LineChart?
I'm working on a LineChart using Recharts where I have two Y-axes representing different datasets. I want to align the zero points of both Y-axes so that they are centered in the chart. Here is my current setup:
import {
  LineChart,
  Line,
  XAxis,
  YAxis,
  CartesianGrid,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  ResponsiveContainer,
} from 'recharts';

const data = [
  { t: 1, current: 0, lift: 0 },
  { t: 35, current: 300, lift: 2 },
  { t: 55, current: 300, lift: 2 },
  { t: 56, current: 700, lift: 2 },
  { t: 96, current: 700, lift: 2 },
  { t: 97, current: 100, lift: 2 },
  { t: 117, current: 100, lift: 2 },
  { t: 118, current: 0, lift: 0 },
  { t: 119, current: 0, lift: -4 },
  { t: 138, current: 0, lift: -4 },
];

const Overview = () => {
  const minCurrent = Math.min(...data.map((item) => item.current));
  const maxCurrent = Math.max(...data.map((item) => item.current));
  const minLift = Math.min(...data.map((item) => item.lift));
  const maxLift = Math.max(...data.map((item) => item.lift));

  // Domains calculated to center zero
  const maxAbsValue = Math.max(Math.abs(minCurrent), Math.abs(maxCurrent), Math.abs(minLift), Math.abs(maxLift));
  const centeredDomain = [-maxAbsValue, maxAbsValue];

  return (
    <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height={300}>
      <LineChart data={data}>
        <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
        <XAxis dataKey="t" />
        <YAxis yAxisId="current" domain={centeredDomain} unit=" A" />
        <YAxis yAxisId="lift" orientation="right" domain={centeredDomain} unit=" mm" />
        <Tooltip />
        <Legend />
        <Line yAxisId="current" type="monotone" dataKey="current" stroke="#a72226" />
        <Line yAxisId="lift" type="monotone" dataKey="lift" stroke="#82ca9d" />
      </LineChart>
    </ResponsiveContainer>
  );
};

export default Overview;


This setup attempts to center the zero points by calculating symmetric domains for both Y-axes, but the result is that one of the lines (especially the "lift" line) becomes hard to read due to the scaling.
Is there a better way to align the zero points of both Y-axes while still keeping the charts readable? How can I adjust the scaling or the setup to improve the visibility of both data series?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

I have solved it like this
const minCurrent = Math.min(...data.map((item) => item.current))
const maxCurrent = Math.max(...data.map((item) => item.current))
const minLift = Math.min(...data.map((item) => item.lift))
const maxLift = Math.max(...data.map((item) => item.lift))
    
const maxAbsCurrent = Math.max(Math.abs(minCurrent), Math.abs(maxCurrent))
const maxAbsLift = Math.max(Math.abs(minLift), Math.abs(maxLift))
    
const currentDomain = [-maxAbsCurrent, maxAbsCurrent]
const liftDomain = [-maxAbsLift, maxAbsLift]

